# Autocomplete-paths выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Работаю в Атоме, плагин `autocomplete-paths` выдает ошибку.

> Maximum file count of 2000 has been exceeded. Path autocompletion will not work in this project.

Посмотрел в гугле: проблема в том, что в папке `node_modules` много файлов? вот и происходит ошибка в плагине. Был совет добавить в `Ignored Names` строчку `node_modules/`, но в новых версиях, наверное, убрали строку для добавления конкретных папок для игнора и оставили только чекбокс, и теперь я не знаю, что делать с этой ошибкой, может быть кто-то встречал подобное?

Comment: у меня тоже такая проблема, вот только от этого плагин не прекращает свою работу, а алерт вылезает только при запуске Атома

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лан, ты меня заставил пересмотреть настройки)
Включаешь тот чекбокс в плагие, переходишь в кор настройки, там будет Ignore Names
впиши туда node_modules/
Если не поможет то в настройке плагина есть строка с дефолтной настройкой 2000
поставь 10000 и перестанет вылезать ошибка